# What is the red-outlined white square that contains a red dot in this diagram?

Tags: diagram, stripboard

I'm new to circuit design and reading schematics but have a little familiarity there. On this diagram which shows a circuit built on a strip board, I don't quite understand the meaning of the red-outlined white square that contains a red dot.

[image]

Comment: You should cut the strip there.

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess that the red dot and square indicate a cut in the copper track - there should be no connection between the track sections to the left and right of that symbol.  (but it would be nice to have a schematic of that circuit to verify my guess)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a schematic, but this makes sense. So in theory, if I had an 8x7 board, i could just run the 100n cap and volume one above where the rest of the circuit is without a cut.